# java.lang.NullPointerException on a static list.isEmpty() operation

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I have a problem and been stuck to it. I've no idea how to solve it and **why actually it occurs**. Actually, I have a **static list** defined and initialized in some class "Utilities". I start the (android) application i.e. the first activity then goes onto second activity and check

```
if(Utilities.myList.isEmpty()) {

    // load data from server
} else {

   // skip
}
```

First time it runs ok. No exception, no prblem. Then I press the back button (goes to first activity again)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    finish() ;
    super.onBackPressed() ;
}
```

Then Again come back to the second activity And gets exception here **java.lang.NullPointerException** on the if-condition i.e. "Utilities.myList.isEmpty()" and

> Utilities.myList gives me "null" value

The list inside Utilities class

```
public static List<BranchInfo> myList= new ArrayList<BranchInfo>() ;
```

Comment: Did you initialize the list? Where? Show us.

Comment: Where/when is that if() called?

Comment: yup public static List<BranchInfo> myList = new ArrayList<BranchInfo>() ; As I explained, it runs first time but gives exception on second time

Comment: @Ridcully in onCreate() when activity2 starts

Comment: @Inn_vita Where do you initialize it though? Add it to your question.

Comment: Try adding a final to your declaration of the list. This prevents it to be changed and if it is changed anywhere an exception should be thrown there.

Comment: In a common class "Utilities" (not in activity2 or in activity1)

Comment: Please add the code to show the declaration for myList, the initialiser and where you call the initialiser from.

Comment: @Simon already added in comment above...

Comment: No.  Add the code to your question.

Comment: It would be helpful to have all the code from all the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign memory to list in onCreate method of your activity ,in which you are using it.
Make a method in your Utility class to do so and call it in onCreate of your Activity in which you are using Utilities.myList.

Comment: Ok. But why it runs first time

Comment: The answer is inside your Utility class,either you are not managing list with your activities life cycle or you are initializing it in wrong way.Also post your utility class.